# Spark HiveContext - reading from external partitioned Hive table delimiter issue

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, hivecontext

I have an external partitioned Hive table with underling file ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
Reading data via Hive directly is just fine, but when using Spark's Dataframe API the delimiter '|' is not taken into consideration.

Create external partitioned table:

```
hive> create external table external_delimited_table(value1 string, value2 string)
partitioned by (year string, month string, day string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
location '/client/edb/poc_database/external_delimited_table';
```

Create data file containg just one row and place it to external partitioned table location:

```
shell>echo "one|two" >> table_data.csv
shell>hadoop fs -mkdir -p /client/edb/poc_database/external_delimited_table/year=2016/month=08/day=20
shell>hadoop fs -copyFromLocal table_data.csv /client/edb/poc_database/external_delimited_table/year=2016/month=08/day=20
```

Make partition active:

```
hive> alter table external_delimited_table add partition (year='2016',month='08',day='20');
```

Sanity check:

```
hive> select * from external_delimited_table;
select * from external_delimited_table;
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------+--+
| external_delimited_table.value1  | external_delimited_table.value2  | external_delimited_table.year  | external_delimited_table.month  | external_delimited_table.day  |
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------+--+
| one                              | two                              | 2016                           | 08                              | 20
```

Spark code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
object TestHiveContext {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test Hive Context")

    val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
    val hiveContext  = new HiveContext(spark)

    val dataFrame: DataFrame = hiveContext.sql("SELECT * FROM external_delimited_table")
    dataFrame.show()

    spark.stop()
  }
```

dataFrame.show() output:

```
+-------+------+----+-----+---+
| value1|value2|year|month|day|
+-------+------+----+-----+---+
|one|two|  null|2016|   08| 20|
+-------+------+----+-----+---+
```

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be a problem with Spark version 1.5.0. In version 1.6.0 issue doesn't take place:

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("select * from external_delimited_table")
res2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value1: string, value2: string, year: string, month: string, day: string]

scala> res2.show
+------+------+----+-----+---+
|value1|value2|year|month|day|
+------+------+----+-----+---+
|   one|   two|2016|   08| 20|
+------+------+----+-----+---+
```